# How to block css cache without adding random number to it?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, caching, browser

I have an angular project,which when uploaded to the server the css files are getting cached and the previous version files are served.So,then I started adding something like

```
 <link src="assets/custom.css?version=1"></link>
```

At the end of my files,so the cache issue is fixed.

Another story in between is my site has some pages which has question mark in its url example,

```
www.mysite.com/home?login
```

I dont want google to crawl this page,so we decided to put a setting that all url's with question mark should not be crawl by google.So,those '?' mark url's are blocked.

Here because of this my css file is also getting blocked and crawl by the google since it has question mark in it.

SO,is there any other way to block css cahce with adding '?' random number to it.I am very happy to follow the suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timestamp behind file name, i.e, **custom-1515043221.css**.

Check this out : [**gulp-rev**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev), it is a gulp plugin which adds random string behind file to stop it from caching.

You can also do this manually by writing gulp task,

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

gulp.task('default', ['add-timestamp', 'rename']);

// add timestamp behind files in index.html
gulp.task('add-timestamp', function () {
  gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(replace('style.min', 'style.min-' + timestamp))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});

// append timestamp behind files in build
gulp.task('rename', function () {
  gulp.src(['build/css/*.css'])
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      if (path.basename === 'style.min') {
        path.basename += '-' + timestamp;
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
      return file.base;
    }));
});
```

Then run this gulpfile using **gulp** command

Comment: Thanks Noopur,seems the best solution.Can I change the file name and the the same name given in the src in one shot.

Comment: Just change path in gulp task `rename` from build to src

Comment: I would never have guessed OP is using grunt, gulp or something else since it is never mentioned in the question.

Comment: Using gulp with angularjs is considered as best approach, since gulp is considered as best building tool for generating build. If there is angular2+, then there is webpack which automatically do the job. And OP is open for suggestions.

Comment: Well, I am using `grunt` myself.